# Moving CSS to separate file makes it not function

Tags: html, css

I am using JSSOR Image gallery:

As you can see above at the bottom I am trying to remove the css from the page.

Putting it in a css file makes it not function however.

Also, putting it in its own unique file and replacing the CSS also makes it not function. That is to change this:

```css
/* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
/*
.jssora05l                  (normal)
.jssora05r                  (normal)
.jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
.jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
.jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
.jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
*/
.jssora05l, .jssora05r {
display: block;
position: absolute;
/* size of arrow element */
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
cursor: pointer;
background: url(../img/a17.png) no-repeat;
overflow: hidden;
}
.jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
.jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
.jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
.jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
.jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
.jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
```

```html
  <div id="sliderb_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 850px;
     height: 565px; overflow: hidden; margin-bottom:25px;">
     <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
           background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
           top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="slides" u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 850px; height: 565px;
        overflow: hidden;">
        <div>
           <div class="portrait" u=image style="background-image: url(../img/zachry/1.jpg">&nbsp;</div>
           <div u="thumb"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <img u=image src="../img/zachry/2.jpg"  />
           <div u="thumb"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <div class="portrait" u=image style="background-image: url(../img/zachry/3.jpg">&nbsp;</div>
           <div u="thumb"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <div class="portrait" u=image style="background-image: url(../img/zachry/4.jpg">&nbsp;</div>
           <div u="thumb"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <img u=image src="../img/zachry/5.jpg" />
           <div u="thumb"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <img u=image src="../img/zachry/6.jpg" />
           <div u="thumb"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
           <div class="portrait" u=image style="background-image: url(../img/zachry/7.jpg">&nbsp;</div>
           <div u="thumb"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div u="thumbnavigator" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height:45px; width:600px;">
        <div u="slides">
           <div u="prototype" >
              <div u="thumbnailtemplate" style="font-family: verdana; font-weight: normal; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; color:#fff; line-height: 45px; font-size:20px; padding-left:10px;"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/src/image-gallery2.css">
     <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="bottom: 16px; right: 10px;">
        <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
        <div u="prototype"></div>
     </div>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/src/image-gallery3.css">

     <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top: 123px; left: 8px;">
     </span>
     <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top: 123px; right: 8px;">
     </span>
  </div>
```

To this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/src/image-gallery3.css">
```

Where that file contains the above css.

But when I do this it no longer works. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: where is the css file in relation to the HTML file?

Comment: The console is a great tool in all browsers, perhaps there's something wrong with the the link to that stylesheet, having that said, open up the console and look for any errors.

Comment: if it doesn't work in the external file, then you're not loading the file. e.g. check your JS console, check the server's error logs for 404s, etc...

Comment: You must put the <link rel="........ in the head of the document.

Comment: It appears to be something to do with the heirarchy and its effect on the css. When i use the important! tag on everything it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix it follow this checklist:

1. All CSS **style** elements or **link** elements must go in the head section of your html document.
2. If you CSS code is in an external file, you need to remove the  and  tags.
3. You need to make sure your relative path is set up correctly. For example if your html page is located in the "www" directory and your css file is located in the "www/css/src" directory, your link should work. If, however, your page is in "www/pages" and your css is in "www/css/src" you need to adjust your link accordingly (i.e. in this example it would be "../css/src" rather than just "css/src".
4. Make sure permissions on your css file are set to **readable** by the web server.

Also, be aware that if you have multiple style and link elements the last one declared will take precedence if there are any conflicting declarations.